# Помогите решить проблему CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, grid

Я не могу никак сделать чтоб верхние 2 элемента были width: 412px; height: 220px; color: #011E1E;
А нижние 2 - width: 842px; height: 220px; color: #011E1E;

И это с помощью CSS Grid

Должно быть вот так:

[image: Должно быть вот так]

Comment: прежде чем задавать новый вопрос , стоит принять ответ на старый

Comment: Я не могу его принять

Comment: в чем проблема ? под вопросом есть галочка

Comment: Вы можете помочь, пожалуйста?

Comment: @RuslanMelikov ширину нижних элементов вы возможно имели ввиду 824, а не 842, да?

Comment: Мне кажется на гридах это нельзя сделать, даже если 824

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0;   width:100vw;
  height:100vh;}

.main{

}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 412px 412px;
  grid-template-rows: 220px 220px 220px;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "test1 test2"
    "test3 test3"
    "test4 test4";
  grid-gap : 10px; 
  ba #001f20;
}

.test1 { grid-area: test1;}

.test2 { grid-area: test2; }

.test3 { grid-area: test3; }

.test4 { grid-area: test4; }

.grid-container div{
   background:#011E1E;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test2"></div>
  <div class="test3"></div>
  <div class="test4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как их сделать кликабельными?

Comment: @RuslanMelikov поместить туда например кнопку, с шириной и высотой 100%

Comment: @RuslanMelikov можете посмотреть, я добавил ссылку

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, max-content);
  grid-template-areas: "a a";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid__item {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(n+3) {
  background-color: red;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(1),
.grid__item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: a;
}

.grid__link {
  color: inherit;
}

.grid__link::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #95d32a;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
}

.grid__link:hover::before {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid__container">
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <a class="grid__link" href="https://css-tricks.com/">Тыкни меня!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```